# App crashes trying to send data to phpmyadmin

Tags: android, onclicklistener

My app crashes when I try the following code to call a method onclick.

Full activity:

```
public class UserCom extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;
private ArrayList<Order> m_orders = null;
private OrderAdapter m_adapter;
private Runnable viewOrders; 
private Thread t;

String valcom;
String valnm;
EditText editText1;
EditText editText2;
URL url;
InputStream is;
HttpURLConnection h;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_com);

    View subBTN  = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    subBTN.setOnClickListener(this);

    m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    this.m_adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, R.layout.listlook, m_orders);
            setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

    viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getOrders();
        }
    };
Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(UserCom.this,    
          "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_com, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            sendTextToDB();
            break;
    }
    }

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
        }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static JSONArray readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
try {
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,  Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  String jsonText = readAll(rd);
  JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonText);
  return json;
} finally {
  is.close();
}
}

private void getOrders(){

    m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    JSONArray json; 
    JSONObject jo;
    try{

        json = readJsonFromUrl("http://10.0.2.2/HB/hikebuddy.php?function=usercomm");

        jo = (JSONObject) json.get(0); 

        Order o1 = new Order();
        o1.setOrderName(jo.get("comment").toString());
        o1.setOrderStatus(jo.get("name").toString());
//            Order o2 = new Order();
//          o2.setOrderName("SF Advertisement");
 //        o2.setOrderStatus("Completed");
        m_orders.add(o1);
  //      m_orders.add(o2);
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
      }
      runOnUiThread(returnRes);
  }

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
            m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  };

  private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

      private ArrayList<Order> items;

      public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
              super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
              this.items = items;
      }
      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              View v = convertView;
              if (v == null) {
                  LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                  v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listlook, null);
              }
              Order o = items.get(position);
              if (o != null) {
                      TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtl1);
                      TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtl2);
                      if (tt != null) {
                            tt.setText(o.getOrderName());                            }
                      if(bt != null){
                            bt.setText(o.getOrderStatus());
                      }
              }
              return v;
      }
 }




public void sendTextToDB() {

valcom = editText1.getText().toString();
valnm = editText2.getText().toString(); 

    t = new Thread() {
public void run() {
try {
url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/HB/hikebuddy.php?function=setcomm&comment="+valcom+"&name="+valnm);
h = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

if( h.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
is = h.getInputStream();

  // do something with the data here
  }else{
is = h.getErrorStream();

}

  h.disconnect();

} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
Log.d("Test", "CONNECTION FAILED 1");
}
}
};

t.start();

}
}
```

How do i fix this?

Logcat errors:

10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.example.hikebuddy.UserCom.sendTextToDB(UserCom.java:193)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.example.hikebuddy.UserCom.onClick(UserCom.java:92)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-21 16:56:00.198: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: make sure you have added internet permission in AndroidManifest and also post stack trace when application crashing with question to get more help

Comment: Internet permission is added, the app already calls the data, now I have to send it. Not sure what the stack trace is, but I posted the logcat errors.

Comment: Post your full activity.

Comment: @dkgeld: what is line number 193 in UserCom class?

Comment: line 193 is: valcom = editText1.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to initialize EditText before calling `EditText.getText()` method so initialize after `setContentView` as :

```
EditText editText1;
EditText editText2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_com);

     editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edittextid);
     editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edittextid);
    .....
```

Comment: Can not BELIEVE I forgot that! Thanks :)